# Fetch ONLY playable videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to fetch **only** the videos that can be played in an iFrame YouTube player in an iOS device? Having set the parameter **videoEmbeddable=true** there are still some videos that I cannot play on my iPhone, and I have to manually try each video to see if I get an `onError` back. Any solution?

Comment: did you tried videoSyndicated=true ?

Comment: Yes I tried it but it still has the same problem.